# PySpark : sum RDD values , keep the key

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

Just started with Spark

I have rdd like following :

> (x,(a,1))

I'd like sum each **a** as folowing

```
sumRDD = filteredRdd.map(lambda (x, (a, b)): (a, b)).reduceByKey(add)
```

It's works
then , I'd like to add **x** as it was previously ,like this

```
(x,(a,sum_of_a))
```

I tried :

```
 sumRDD = filteredRdd.map(lambda (x, (a, b)): (a, b)).reduceByKey(add).map(lambda (a, b): (x,(a, b)))
```

it fails :(

**Edit** : I'd like to keep  x during calculation the sum of b , it's my important key

Answer (score 1):

After you calculate  `sumRDD` you have two RDD's -
`sumRDD` of the form `(a, sum_of_a)` and `filteredRdd` of the form `(x, (a,b))`.

You actually want to create a join of the were the key is `a` and then map back.

I would do something like -

`newRdd = filteredRdd.map(lambda x: (x[1][0], x[0])).join(sumRDD)`

After this phase you will have output of the sort -
`a, (x, sum_of_a)`

And now you need to transform it to the format you like so -

`newRdd = newRdd.map(lambda x: (x[1][0], (x[0], x[1][1])))`

Comment: Thanks ! Nice solution ! I have to apologize , by mistake I didn't expalin well the question . I'd like to keep  x during calculation the sum of b , it's my important key